# Inflate layout with context class

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-activity, layout-inflater

I have two activities with two corresponding layouts:

`MainActivity.java` -> `content_main.xml`

`SecondActivity.java` -> `content_secondclass.xml`

My MainActivity inflates the `content_secondclass.xml` without problems:

```
RelativeLayout mainLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.content_main);
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.content_secondclass, null);
mainLayout.removeAllViews();
mainLayout.addView(layout);
```

How do I give this inflation the context of `SecondActivity.java` though? I do not want to start another Intent since it would open in a new window and I am using a Navigation Drawer style application. I want SecondActivity to be called when I inflate the content_secondclass.xml, but right now it is only inflating the content_secondclass without calling SecondActivity.java.

My content_secondclass.xml already has the `tools:context` tag of ".SecondActivity"

Hope I got my point across. Thank you very much for your time and assistance in this matter.

Comment: Look for something called "fragments" in google.

Comment: this is not how an activty inflates the xml layout instead use setcontentview on oncreate

Answer (score 1):

I understood your problem a little. As my guess you want some java work in your second layout(view) inside your first(Main) layout without opening another activity.

Best way to do this using fragments. Using fragments you will have flexible UI and each fragments have corresponding java controller in one activity. If you are new to android go through fragment tutorial. Some basics about fragments [click here](https://www.raywenderlich.com/149112/android-fragments-tutorial-introduction)

Best Regards

Comment: thanks for the answers to both of you, will definitely look into fragments.

Answer (score 0):

The main layout which holds the navigation drawer should be a frame layout and create object of frame layout and

```
  FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment);
        transaction.addToBackStack(tag);
        transaction.commit();
```

here fragment is the object of your created fragment